# Sql mapping problems

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I have `CustomDBContext`:

```
public class CustomDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomDBContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            ......
            modelBuilder.Entity<KeyProd>().ToTable("KeyProd");
            ......
        }
    }
```

And Repository registration in Startup.cs:

```
.....
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => RepositoryFactory.GetInstance<KeyProd, long>("ef")).As<IRepository<KeyProd, long>>().InstancePerRequest();
```

After injection of this repository to my service, i try to add new row to database:

```
_keyProductionRepository.Add(new KeyProd
                        {
                            Id = key.Id,
                            Comment = key.Comment,
                            CreatedBy = adminId,
                            DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            KeyType = key.KeyType,
                            PageId = key.PageId,
                            Name = key.Name
                        });
```

The exception is: 
*Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'ln_resources.dbo.KeyProd'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.*

The model i try to insert have id (3). Is not null.I checked it in debug mode.

My table in SQl without autoincremented Id. This is a query of table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyProd](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [KeyType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [text] NULL,
    [PageId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [DateUpdated] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdatedBy] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KeyProd]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_KeyProd_Page] FOREIGN KEY([PageId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Page] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KeyProd] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_KeyProd_Page]
GO
```

My `KeyProd` Class:

```
  public class KeyProd
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public KeyType KeyType { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    }
```

If i try to insert this model directly from `SQL SERVER` by using `SQL INSERT`, all works fine. 
Where the problem? Why Id is Null? Why mapping not working.

Comment: Can you please post a simplified version of your `KeyProd` class including the `Id` field?

Comment: Hi Mike C. Of course

Answer (score 0):

You may need to annotate the key field on `KeyProd` to indicate that you don't want the value to be automatically generated by your context.  Try adding `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` to your key property.

```
public class KeyProd {

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // ... Other properties
}
```